# Testing of the PhpBB forum

Tags: htmlunit

I am testing forum PhpBB with help of HTML unit. I want to add message in one of topic of PhpBB forum. I enter the message in textarea and click the submit button, but new page doesn't have my message. What seems to be the problem?

```
final ArrayList<HtmlForm> formList=(ArrayList<HtmlForm>) page.getByXPath("//form[@id='postform']");  
final HtmlTextArea myMessage=formList.get(0).getTextAreaByName("message");
myMessage.type("text");
final HtmlSubmitInput submit_post = formList.get(0).getInputByName("post");

page=submit_post.click();

if (page.asText().contains("text")) {
  System.out.println("right");
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to construct a custom http post request.

Use FIddler to capture the traffic and then replicate it with HTMLUnit. It should look something like below

```
public Page postMessage() throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL("YOURURL");
    WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST);

    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", "REFERER");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");

    requestSettings
            .setRequestBody("YOURPOSTREQUEST");

    Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);

    return page;
}
```